# Spring REST maven project configuration & running

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I'm a beginner with Java/Spring/Rest/...

I have the following project where I try to develop a rest ws that will acces Oracle database. 
For this project I'm using the last version of Spring and also JPA.

The maven project has the following struncture:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynhYe.png)

The service classes are working fine, including the advice part (I verified that using a simple test class with a main method).

The problem is that I can't get the rest controller to work (I also tried a SOAP based service but I had problems wit autowiring).

The application is deploying on Tomcat but I can't find any exposed resources (I'm using Rest Shell for testing).

Here is some additional files from the project:
pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>BRISService</groupId>
  <artifactId>BRISService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>BRIS REST Service</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
   <dependencies>   
   <!-- Spring Framework -->
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency> 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency> 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency> 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
 </dependency>      
 
 <!-- Datasource --> 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
 </dependency>  
 
 <!-- JPA -->
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <!-- <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
   <version>12.1.0.2</version>
 </dependency> -->
 
 <!-- log4j -->
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.0.redhat-2</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.2</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
     <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.10</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
     <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.10</version>
 </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>BRISService</display-name>
   
   <context-param>
   <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
   
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/Dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>       
    </servlet>
  
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>       
    </servlet-mapping>   

   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
 
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/application.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 

 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

 <!-- we are using autowiring and component scanning for our beans you can 
  wire them manually if you prefer -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="ro.onrc.bris"/>
 
 <!-- This will automatically switch on the default httpmessageconverters -->
 <mvc:annotation-driven/> 

</beans>
```

application.xml:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"     

 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

 <!-- we are using autowiring and component scanning for our beans you can 
  wire them manually if you prefer -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="ro.onrc.bris">
  <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
 </context:component-scan>
 
 <!-- Datasources -->
 <bean id="datasource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172..../..."/>
        <property name="user" value="..."/>
        <property name="password" value="..."/>
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean> 
 
 <!--  and automatic transactions -->
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/> 
  </bean>
  <tx:annotation-driven />  

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
   </bean>
  </property>  
    </bean>
    
    <!-- AOP -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    
    <!-- Advice -->
    <bean id="serviceAdvice" class="ro.onrc.bris.advice.ServiceAdvice"/>
 
</beans>
```

My service class:

```html
package ro.onrc.bris.service.impl;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import ro.onrc.bris.dao.CompanyDao;
import ro.onrc.bris.exception.NoResultsFoundException;
import ro.onrc.bris.model.Company;
import ro.onrc.bris.service.CompanyService;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

 @Autowired
 CompanyDao companydao;  
 
 @Override
 public Company searchByID(UUID id) throws NoResultsFoundException 
 {
  Company company = companydao.searchByID(id);
  if (company == null)
   throw new NoResultsFoundException();
  
  return company;
 }

 @Override
 public List<Company> searchByFiscalCode(String fiscalcode) throws NoResultsFoundException 
 {
  List<Company> companies = companydao.searchByFiscalCode(fiscalcode);
  if (companies == null)
   throw new NoResultsFoundException();
  
  return companies;
 }

 @Override
 public Company searchByRegistrationNumber(String registrationnumber) throws NoResultsFoundException 
 {
  Company company = companydao.searchByRegistrationNumber(registrationnumber);
  if (company == null)
   throw new NoResultsFoundException();
  
  return company;
 }

}
```

My rest controller class:

```html
package ro.onrc.bris.ws;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import ro.onrc.bris.exception.NoResultsFoundException;
import ro.onrc.bris.model.Company;
import ro.onrc.bris.service.CompanyService;

@RestController("/bris")
public class CompanyRESTService
{
 @Autowired
 private CompanyService companyservice; 
 
 @RequestMapping(value="company/{fiscalcode}")
 public List<Company> searchByFiscalCode(@PathVariable String fiscalcode) throws NoResultsFoundException {
  return companyservice.searchByFiscalCode(fiscalcode);
 } 
}
```

Please help me configuring this project.

Comment: why do you exclude the Controller annotation from the autoscan?

Comment: Because the full <<context:component-scan> is made in the Dispatcher-servlet. Anyway, I 'borrowed' this part of code from another (mvc) application. For sure I can improve this part of code.

Comment: Just include Controllers in Dispatcher servlet and exclude others. And on root application context, just include everything except Controllers.

Comment: I made this modification as follows:
in Dispatcher-servlet:
**<context:component-scan base-package="ro.onrc.bris">
  <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>  
 </context:component-scan>**

In application.xml:
**<context:component-scan base-package="ro.onrc.bris">
  <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
 </context:component-scan>**

Still rest does not work :(.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem which was linked to the structure of the maven project.